# Simulating the Monty Hall Problem in Javascript

Tags: javascript, simulator

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

I was super intrigued by the Monty Hall problem, and it's really hard to wrap my head around. I'm a beginner in Javascript, so I decided to try and simulate the problem to get a better feel for how it worked. However, in my simulation, I got around 33% for whether you switched or didn't switch. I was wondering if any of you could help to see why that is. Thanks in advance!!

Here is the Javascript code that I used to try to simulate switching and not switching in the Monty Hall problem.

```js
function overAndOver(switchn,num) {
  let choices = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
  let truth = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  let wins = 0; 
  let losses = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    let check = theHall(choices,switchn);
    if (check == 1) {
      wins += 1;
    } else {
      losses += 1;
    }
  }
  let winPercent = wins/num;
  console.log("Your wins are " + wins);
  console.log("Your losses are " + losses);
  console.log("You tried " + num + " times");
  console.log("Your win percent is " + winPercent);
}

function theHall(choice, switching){
  let realDoor = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  let fakeDoor;
  let array = [1,2,3];
  if(realDoor == 1) {
    fakeDoor == 2 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
  } else if(realDoor == 2) {
    let check = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
      if(check == 1) {
        check = -1;
      } else if(check == 0) {
        check = 1;
      }
    fakeDoor = 2 + check;
  } else if(realDoor == 3) {
    fakeDoor = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  }
  if(switching == "true") {
    array.pop(choice - 1);
    array.pop(fakeDoor - 1);
    choice = array[0];
  } 

  if(choice == realDoor) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

overAndOver("true",100);
console.log("");
overAndOver("false",100);
```

Comment: Your code is picking a new "real" door on each iteration; that's not how the problem is defined. In the actual TV show, there were physical curtains and physical objects behind the curtain. Thus the "real" door was set at the beginning of the entire process, and did not change.

Comment: This is the Evil Monty Hall variation.

Comment: *"it's really hard to wrap my head around"* - You're probably overthinking it.  Regardless of any given simulation, just look at the number of doors.  There are 3 possible options.  The contestant selects 1 of the 3, the host (by default) has 2 of the 3.  Who is more likely to have the winning door?  The person with 1/3 of the options, or the person with 2/3 of the options?  The rest is just smoke and mirrors to distract the contestant from those numbers.

Comment: There really isn't any need to simulate, there are only 9 possible scenarios (3 initial choices for the player x 3 positions that can contain the prize) and you can enumerate them in about 30 seconds on paper and tally the results.

Comment: Take a look at https://medium.com/@nitinpatel_20236/simulating-monty-hall-problem-in-javascript-1f86dfd26d9d